# How to store the login username in a cookie in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, authentication

I want to store the login username in a cookie which expires in 2 weeks or so.  I also want the login view to fill the username from the cookie.  No "remember me" checkbox or any authentication code necessary.

Based upon the answer below, here's the pseudo-code I got working:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize

  def new
    params[:username] = cookies[:username] unless cookies[:username].nil?
  end

  def create
    if user
      cookies[:username] = {:value => params[:username].downcase, :expires => 2.weeks.from_now }
    end
  end

end
```

The majority of the code has been omitted for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the long form to set the cookie value so you can include the expiry...

```
cookies[:username] = { :value => "the_username", :expires => 2.weeks.from_now }
```

Works the same if you want the tamper proof version with `cookies.signed[:username]`

Comment: How do I use it in the Controller or View then? :value => cookies[:username] or :value => cookies[:username][:value] ?

Comment: The `:value` in the code I have above is different from the `:value` in the view.  With my code above, you'd just have: `<%= f.text_field :username, :value => cookie[:username] %>` but you might be better to set it in the controller: `@user.username = cookie[:username]` before rendering your view.

Answer (score 5):

Just set the cookie using the cookie store like this:

```
cookies.signed[:username] = { :value => "username", :expires => 2.weeks.from_now }
```

The .signed makes the cookie "tamper proof".

In your view you'll probably want something like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :username, :value => cookies.signed[:username] %>
```

Comment: When does it expire though?  Will it last client-side for 2 weeks?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that part.  I've updated my answer to include the expiration date.